# get a small-scale image url

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the url of a small-scale version of an image I upload.
I save an image, give it a title, and save a small-resolution image (150X150 or 148X150). I know how to get the image url by its title, but I always get the full-resolution image url.

Do you have any suggestion how I can get the 150X150/148X150 image url?

Comment: Are you looking for a function or a way to do this from the WordPress admin?

Comment: function. I need to it from the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the function [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, array( 150, 150 ) ); // returns an array

// Alternatively, you can pass a second parameter of 'thumbnail', 'small', 
// 'medium' or 'large' instead of an array
?> 

<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
```

Comment: seems like what I'm looking for.. what is the attachment id? how can I get it for the desired image?

Comment: I used http://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/?doing_wp_cron=1341491078.7018549442291259765625 to find the attachment id of my image.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload image you should have 4 files:

```
filename-150x150.jpg
filename-resized_widthx300.jpg
filename-resized_widthx1024.jpg
filename.jpg
```

or

```
filename-150x150.jpg
filename-300xresized_height.jpg
filename-1024xresized_height.jpg
filename.jpg
```

When you insert your uploaded image into a post/page, you can choose what size of image you want to use, for example i can choose:

```
Thumbnail (150 × 150)
Medium (195 × 300)
Large (668 × 1024)
Full Size (2618 × 4013)
```

You need to use *Thumbnail* to get url to 150x150 px image

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to get the thumbnail from the php code. Do you have a code example for that?